# How can I implement search in this Flutter app

Tags: search, flutter

I'm trying to add a search feature to this flutter app since the json file it pulls data from has 7000 results.

Mainly I'm trying to do search for "ctry" and "peopnameincountry". This was ripped from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwHMSxSWIvQ

As is .. it works fine in fetching the json list and the tap to show detail page works as well.

I just need to implement the search on the main page so I don't have to scroll through the thousands of results.

Appreciate any help .. thank you all.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(new UnReached());

class UnReached extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Unreached'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<List<User>> _getUsers() async {

    var data = await http.get("https://cmfiflutterapp.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/UnreachedPeoplesGroup.json");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<User> users = [];

    for(var u in jsonData){

      User user = User(u["ctry"], u["peopnameincountry"], u["population"], u["primarylanguagename"], u["biblestatus"],  u["primaryreligion"],  u["continent"]);

      users.add(user);

    }

    print(users.length);

    return users;

  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getUsers(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            print(snapshot.data);
            if(snapshot.data == null){
              return Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text("Loading...")
                  )
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
//                    leading: CircleAvatar(
//                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
//                          snapshot.data[index].picture
//                      ),
//                    ),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].peopnameincountry),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].ctry),
                    onTap: (){

                      Navigator.push(context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(snapshot.data[index]))
                      );

                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My apologies guys...I ended up taking a slightly different approach which I thought was slightly faster in response than the FutureBuilder approach. Maybe it's just my internet. Not sure.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:progress_indicators/progress_indicators.dart';

class IslandWaves extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<IslandWaves> {
  List<User> _list = [];
  List<User> _search = [];
  var loading = false;
  Future<Null> fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    _list.clear();
    final response = await http.get(
        "https://cmfiflutterapp.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/UnreachedPeoplesGroup.json");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        for (Map i in data) {
          _list.add(User.formJson(i));
          loading = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();

  onSearch(String text) async {
    _search.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    _list.forEach((f) {
      if (f.ctry.contains(text) ||
          f.peopnameincountry.toString().contains(text)) _search.add(f);
    });

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    onChanged: onSearch,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Search", border: InputBorder.none),
                  ),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.clear();
                      onSearch('');
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            loading
                ? Center(
                    heightFactor: 20.0,
                    child: FadingText('Loading...'),
                  )
                : Expanded(
                    child: _search.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                        ? ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: _search.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                              final b = _search[i];
                              return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              DetailPage(_search[i])));
                                  debugPrint('TopNav');
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text(
                                          b.ctry,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 18.0),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 4.0,
                                        ),
                                        Text(b.peopnameincountry),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        : ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: _list.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                              final a = _list[i];
                              return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              DetailPage(_list[i])));
                                  debugPrint('BottomNav');
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text(
                                          a.ctry,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 18.0),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 4.0,
                                        ),
                                        Text(a.peopnameincountry),
                                      ],
                                  )
                                ),
                            );
                        },
                   ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget{....etc.}
```

Comment: Just for you to know, it's not really how SO is supposed to work, you can't ask 3 question in one moreover by answering your own questions with other question. If you have a problem just ask, but if you face a new problem by fixing it, it's a new problem => open another question.

Comment: You seem to be new, so it's ok but consider people coming into your topic to find an answer... They will anoly face new problem --' and even if it's working for you the idea is solving the problem, not bypassing it, this is probably not scalable to others ;)

Comment: My apologies Ferdi, I'm still learning and so thank you for your advise and help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try adding these function in your code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:core';

class HomeScreen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen1> {
  var searchController = new TextEditingController();
  String search;
  List<String> _filterList;
  String _query = "";
  bool _firstSearch = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  HomeScreenState() {
    searchController.addListener(() {
      if (searchController.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _firstSearch = true;
          _query = "";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _firstSearch = false;
          _query = searchController.text;
        });
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _createSearchView(),
            new Expanded(
              child: _firstSearch ? _createListView() : _performSearch(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _createSearchView() {
    return new Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1.0)),
      child: new TextField(
        controller: searchController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          hintText: "Search",
          hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[300]),
        ),
        //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _createListView() {
    return FutureBuilder(
          future: _getUsers(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
            print(snapshot.data);
            if(snapshot.data == null){
              return Container(
                  child: Center(
                      child: Text("Loading...")
                  )
              );
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
//                    leading: CircleAvatar(
//                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
//                          snapshot.data[index].picture
//                      ),
//                    ),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].peopnameincountry),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].ctry),
                    onTap: (){

                      Navigator.push(context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(snapshot.data[index]))
                      );

                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
  }


  Widget _performSearch() {
    return FutureBuilder<List>(builder: (context, snapshot) {
      _filterList = new List<String>();
      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
        var item = snapshot.data[i];
        if ((item.toString().toLowerCase()).contains(_query.toLowerCase())) {

          _filterList.add(item.toString());
        }
      }
      return _createFilteredListView();
    });
  }

  Widget _createFilteredListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _filterList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: new Text("${_filterList[index]}"),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a `FutureBuilder` widget is to be build as soon as it is received, but meanwhile, the snapshot contains no data at all. So when you're calling :

`for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {`

you're, at least at first, calling `length` on `null` since the data is not yet received.

The solution is to create a switch and call `snapshot.data when the status is completed:

```
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return DefaultWidget();         // For instance a CircularProgress

      case ConnectionState.active:
        return DefaultWidget();         // For instance a CircularProgress

      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return DefaultWidget();         // For instance a CircularProgress

      case ConnectionState.done:

        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return ErrorWidget('Error: ${snapshot.error}'); //For example a Text Widget 

         // Your code here:
        _filterList = new List<String>();
      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
        var item = snapshot.data[i];
        if ((item.toString().toLowerCase()).contains(_query.toLowerCase())) {

          _filterList.add(item.toString());
        }
      }
      return _createFilteredListView();
    }
    return null; // unreachable
```

More on this [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Hi Ferdi, I added a switch as you suggested. No more crashing but it's just hanging here on Loading...:  `case ConnectionState.waiting :
        return FadingText(
          'Loading...'
        );`

Comment: Hum... According to your code in your own answer, I would say it's because there is no future to connect with in your widget `_performSearch`, add the parameter `future` as you did for your widget `_createListView`